# Playing with references

Tags: php, reference, binary-operators

I can see why

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['ID'] = 42;
$b = &$a['ID'];
$c = $a;
$c['ID'] = 37;
echo $a['ID']."\n";
echo $b."\n";
echo $c['ID']."\n";
```

outputs 37, 42, 37

while

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['ID'] = 42;
$b = &$a['ID'];
$c = $a;
$b = 37;
echo $a['ID']."\n";
echo $b."\n";
echo $c['ID']."\n";
```

outputs 37, 37, 37

In both cases `$b` is a reference to `$a['ID']` while `$c` is a pointer to the same object as `$a`.

When `$b` changes `$a['ID']` and `$c['ID']` change because assigning `$b` changes the value referenced by `$a['ID']`.

When `$c['ID']` changes, a new int is assigned to `$a['ID']`, `$b` doesn't reference `$a['ID']` anymore.

But this itches me

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['ID'] = 42;
$b = &$a['ID'];
$c = $a;
$c['ID'] &= 0;
$c['ID'] |= 37;
echo $a['ID']."\n";
echo $b."\n";
echo $c['ID']."\n";
```

(outputs 37, 37, 37)

Is this defined behaviour?
I didn't see anything about that in the documentation...

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's documented. The manual only says that ++ and -- perform indirect modification and thus trigger `ArrayAccess::offsetGet()` and not `ArrayAccess::offsetSet()`. For consistency sake, I guess +=, -=, and cousins were implemented in the same manner.

Comment: @cleong I can't seem to find it in the docs. Could you point out where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take this code as a basis:  ( [refcounting documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) )

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['ID'] = 42;
$b = &$a['ID'];
$c = $a;

xdebug_debug_zval('a');
xdebug_debug_zval('b');
xdebug_debug_zval('c');
```

This gives:

```
a:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 42
b:
(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 42
c:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 42
```

As you say:
`$a` is an object, `$b` is a reference of `$a['ID']` ( `$a['ID']` and `$b` : `refcount=2, is_ref=1`)
and $c [is copy as a reference (since PHP5)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), so $c is a reference of $a ( it's now the same object : `refcount=2, is_ref=0`)

---

If we do: `$c['ID'] = 37;`

We get:

```
a:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 37
b:
(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 42
c:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 37
```

`$c['ID']` is assigned a new `int` so =>

`$b` becomes independent (`refcount=1` and `is_ref=0`), as well as `$a['ID']` and `$c['ID']`

BUT as `$c` and `$a` are dependent, `$a['ID']` and `$c['ID']` take the same value 37.

---

Now, let's take the base code and we do: `$c['ID'] &= 0;`

**UPDATE**:
Unexpectedly, we get:

```
a:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 0
b:
(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 0
c:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 0
```

instead of: ( if: `$c['ID'] = $c['ID'] & 0;`)

```
a:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 0
b:
(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 42
c:
(refcount=2, is_ref=0),
object(ArrayObject)[1]
  public 'ID' => (refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 0
```

**ArrayObject implements ArrayAccess so:**

*As said in the comment* and [documented here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php):

*A direct modification is one that replaces completely the value of the array dimension, as in $obj[6] = 7. An indirect modification, on the other hand, only changes part of the dimension, or attempts to assign the dimension by reference to another variable, as in $obj[6][7] = 7 or $var =& $obj[6]. Increments with ++ and decrements with -- are also implemented in a way that requires indirect modification.*

A possible answer:

"Combined Operator (+=, -=, &=, |=) could be worked as the same manner (indirect modification.)":

> `refcount` and `is_ref` are not impacted therefore (in our case) the values of all
>   related variables are modified. (`$c['ID']` =>  `$a['ID']` => `$b)`

Comment: And you don't see how this is _unexpected_ when compared to example 1?

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less defined (but sometimes undocumented) behaviour; mainly because `$a` is not an `array` but an `ArrayObject`.

Let's take a look at your third code fragment first:

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['ID'] = 42;
$b = &$a['ID'];
$c = $a;
$c['ID'] &= 0;
```

The last assignment translates to:

```
$tmp = &$c->offsetGet('ID');
$tmp &= 0; // or: $tmp = $tmp & 0;
```

The take-away point here is *only* [`offsetGet()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetget.php) is called and it returns a *reference* to `$c['ID']`, as noted in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetget.php#79496). Because `offsetSet()` is not called, the value of `$b` changes as well.

*Btw, the increment (++) and decrement operator (--) work in a similar fashion, no `offsetSet()` is called.*

**Differences**

This is different from your first example:

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['ID'] = 42;
$b = &$a['ID'];
$c = $a;
$c['ID'] = 37;
```

The last statement has the following equivalent:

```
$c->offsetSet('ID', 37);
```

Before a new value is assigned to `$c['ID']`, the previous value is effectively `unset()`; this is why `$b` is the only variable still holding on to `42`.

Proof of this behaviour can be seen when you use objects instead of numbers:

```
class MyLoggerObj
{
        public function __destruct()
        {
                echo "Destruct of " . __CLASS__ . "\n";
        }
}

$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['ID'] = new MyLoggerObj();
$a['ID'] = 37;

echo $a['ID']."\n";
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y7Stvp):

```
Destruct of MyLoggerObj
37
```

As you can see, the destructor is called on `MyLoggerObj`; that's because in this case there's no variable holding on to the value anymore.

**Bonus**

If you try to find out when `offsetGet()` and `offsetSet()` are called by extending `ArrayObject` you will be disappointed to find out that you can't properly mimic `mixed &offsetGet($key);`. In fact, doing so changes the behaviour of `ArrayObject` in such a way that it's impossible to prove the behaviour of this class.

Comment: Still not convinced :P, How come that b doesn't get updated in example 1? According to your _expected_ behaviour of offsetSet, it changes the reference (indirect modification), but then b should be 37 aswell.

Comment: I can only guess that other semantics are at work here, but once I get to a computer I'll give that aspect some attention.

Comment: That would make Ex.3 result in 37,42,37 (since the reference $c['id'] is unset by your standards, and after that set to 0).